# Mixed Group Data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-visualization

I'm trying to analyze data that has been mixed and I'm not sure if there's any good way to approach it. I have data from two groups at different periods of time, say 2, 4, 6, and 8 weeks. For weeks 2-6 the data is clearly labeled by groups. However, at week 8 the groups were mixed and given the same treatment and then sampled, and due to inability to tag the individuals I do not know which initial group the samples in the week 8 group came from. My initial thought was to try clustering, but there are two main issues:

1. Because I have my doubts about how random the sampling is, there is a possibility that the sample mixed group does even contain fish from both groups.
2. The separation should be based off of the treatment, so the mixed fish would in theory become homogenous over time. However, since they have only been administered the same treatment for a short period of time, it's possible they are still distinguishable.

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I understand that there were a lot of experimental design issues that complicated this situation, but I didn't have a say in that portion and don't want to waste the data even if its not the best...

I'd be happy to provide more clarification on the situation if necessary.

Comment: To begin, maybe analyze for weeks 2, 4,and 6 only.